# Adding data attribute in form:options, i.e., in options.tag

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I have a list of objects in the pageContext and I want some of it's attribute in the data attribute of the option tag of select.

Below is the jsp code :

```
<form:select class="required chzn_a" disabled="${view}" path="one.id" id="one">
    <form:option value="">Select</form:option>
    <form:options items="${objectList}" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name"/>
</form:select>
```

I want something like below :
[image: With data-code]

However, below is what I am getting :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the form:options tag does not support customization like this. Instead you can loop through the options yourself like this:

```
<form:select class="required chzn_a" disabled="${view}" path="one.id" id="one">
    <form:option value="">Select</form:option>

    <c:forEach items="${objectList}" var="objectListEntry">
        <form:option value="${objectListEntry.id}" data-code="${objectListEntry.code}">${objectListEntry.name}</form:option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

The spring form tags implements the DynamicAttributes interface and all attributes not explicitly defined in the tld are added to the generated tag.

Comment: Thanks, but I was thinking of a different tag in which we can apply this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem how to add an attribute (ISO 3 letter country code) to the options of a select.  A dictionary and a little jQuery worked quite nicely:

```
    var countryDict = {};   // make a dictionary of {country ID : country iso Code}
countryList.forEach(element => {
    countryDict[element.id] = element.iso3Code;
});
$('#myCountry > option').each(function(){  // use that dictionary to add ISO code as an attribute to country options.
    $(this).attr('isoCode', countryDict[$(this).val()]);
});
```