# Multiple selections from dropdown should perform same operation - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dropdown list which has options- A,B,C,D. I want to hide other input fields based on the selection from dropdown.

I can successfully hide fields if user selects A. I dont know how to hide fields if user selects either A or B.

Working Code:

```
$('#lockForm select[name="Key"]').change(function () {
            if ($('#lockForm select[name="Key"] option:selected').val() == 'A') {
                $('.hidden').hide();
            } else {
                $('.hidden').show();
            }
        });

<form:form method="post" id="lockForm">
        <div class="plselect">
            <form:select path="Key">
            <form:option value="NONE" label="------- Select One -------" />
            <form:options items="${List}" itemValue="Code" itemLabel="Desc"/>
            </form:select>
        </div>
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just make two checks in your if statement with an OR:

```
if ($('#lockForm select[name="Key"] option:selected').val() == 'A' || '#lockForm select[name="Key"] option:selected').val() == 'B' )
```

You could clean it up further by saying

```
var selectedOption = $('#lockForm select[name="Key"] option:selected').val();
...
if (selectedOption == 'A' || selectedOption == 'B' )
```

Comment: Thank You. Got the problem with my code - I was doing if (selectedOption == 'A' || 'B') instead of if (selectedOption == 'A' || selectedOption == 'B' ) or if(selectedOption == ('A' || 'B' ))

Comment: I wouldn't use that last format. ('A' || 'B' ) will just evaluate to 'A' since 'A' count as a true value, and gets returned. 'B' isn't even parsed. Type ('A' || 'B' ) into your console and see.

Comment: Conditionals get handled by the computer as a collection of nested statements. They get handled with an order of operations like math. In the first answer, selectedOption == 'A' gets parsed, then the result || 'B' gets parsed. 

('A' == 'A' || 'B')
true

('B' == 'A' || 'B')
"B"

Answer (score 1):

You can gain a full control by telling the script what elements to hide and what to show on option select. You can do it by adding data to option elements this way:

```js
function showHide(e) {
    var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
    $( selectedOption.data('hide') ).hide();
    $( selectedOption.data('show') ).show();
};
$('select')
    .on('change', showHide)
    .trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <select>
        <option data-hide=".user-input" data-show=".user-input-a" value="A">show A</option>
        <option data-hide=".user-input" data-show=".user-input-b" value="B">show B</option>
        <option data-hide=".user-input" data-show=".user-input-c" value="C">show C</option>
        <option data-hide=".user-input" data-show=".user-input-d" value="D">show D</option>
        <option data-hide=".user-input" data-show=".user-input-a,.user-input-d" value="AD">show A and D</option>
        <option data-hide=".user-input" data-show="" value="">hide all</option>
        <option data-hide="" data-show=".user-input" value="ABCD">show all</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p class="user-input user-input-a">
    A - any content
</p>
<p class="user-input user-input-b">
    B - any content
</p>
<p class="user-input user-input-c">
    C - any content
</p>
<p class="user-input user-input-d">
    D - any content
</p>
```

This way you can use it on any select on your page, no need to change Javascript code any more, just add attributes in HTML.

Same code on [Playground](https://jsfiddle.net/roL3f4oj/).

Comment: I am geeting the dropdownlist using @ModelAttribute.             <form:options items="${List}" itemValue="Code" itemLabel="Desc"/>

Comment: You can loop the options [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543997/adding-data-attribute-in-formoptions-i-e-in-options-tag#answer-33549285) and add attributes.